# Gcard with six panels

Tags: minipage

I want to make a card in latex with six panels. Sorry for the crude explanation, but something like this: \__/, that is, the card folds both from the left and the right, with the two edges meeting in the middle. So you have, for example, the following panels:

- Front left: 3" x 6"
- Front right: 3" x 6"
- Inside left: back of front left
- Inside middle: 6" x 6"
- Inside right: back of front right
- Back: back of inside middle

I found the gcard package which allows for four panels like a regular card. Is it possible to alter the gcard package to allow for this?

Comment: I think you want a *brochure*. How about `leaflet` class?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether I understood your question properly. It seems you want to produce a brochure. `leaflet` class is more suitable for such work.

```
\documentclass[foldmark,10pt,a4paper,notumble,notwopart*]{leaflet}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[scaled=.93]{libertine}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

For details `texdoc leaflet` from command line or [visit texdoc.net](http://www.texdoc.net)

Comment: Does this allow one of the columns to be double width? That would work fine I think.

Comment: @Venning: I am afraid no.